# Create groups of pair of IDs, with each group having IDs in common

Tags: r, algorithm, relationship

I have the following data:

```
a <- structure(list(ID.x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 6), ID.y = c(2, 4, 5, 3,
7), var.x = c(55, 82, 32, 94, 55), var.y = c(86, 24, 68, 63,
77)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

```
> a
  ID.x ID.y var.x var.y
1    1    2    55    86
2    2    4    82    24
3    3    5    32    68
4    1    3    94    63
5    6    7    55    77
```

I need to create a variable so that, given pairs of `ID`, all the pairs that are connected by an element in common in the `ID` variables have the same code.

For instance:

- Pair 1 (1 and 2) have ID_group = 1
- Pair 2 (2 and 4) has 2 in common with Pair 1, so it would have ID_pair = 1
- Pair 3 (3 and 5) has no element in common with Pair 1 and 2, but it has 3 in common with Pair 4 (which in turn has 1 in common with Pair 1), so it should still be 1
- Pair 4 (1 and 3) would be pair 1, as it has one element in common with Pair 1 and 2
- Pair 5 has no element in common with anything, so it should be 2 (or whatever)

The desired outcome would be

```
> a
  ID.x ID.y var.x var.y ID_group
1    1    2    55    86       1
2    2    4    82    24       1
3    3    5    32    68       1
4    1    3    94    63       1
5    6    7    55    77       2
```

Some extra notes that might be helpful:

1. ID_pair is categorical (and so are all the ID variables) and does not need to be sequential, just unique for each group. I am just using numbers as it has to be done with 22k entries.
2. If it helps conceptualising it, the IDs represent related individuals. ID_group would be an identifier family they belong to.
3. The data does not have to stay in this paired form, but it can also be in "long" form (I need to pair/unpair it often).
4. A solution in R would be best, but I am more interested in the algorithm to obtain it than in the actual coding

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I appreciate the title and some bits of the question might be a mindfuck, happy to take on suggestions to describe this better

Comment: This looks like a common problem in network analysis. I think if you search for "igraph" and "cliques" you will find relevant answers.

Comment: The assignment for Pair 3 is kind of moving back and forth, isn't it? Ideally, it should be Pair 3->2, then check Pair 4-> 1 in common so it will be 1-> then a change in Pair 3 as it contains 3.

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks for the heads up. I am having a look at what a clique is, are they the same thing? What I am reading as of now is that they're fully connected subgraphs of a graph, but I think my situation is that I have different unconnected graphs. E.g. 1 and 2 have no elements in common

Comment: @Shibaprasadb yes, that would be correct. It would be terribly inefficient in the way I described it as it must be scaled up to 22k pairs, so any better way would do, really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

Using igraph:

```
library(igraph)

memb <- components(graph_from_data_frame(a))$membership
a$ID_group <- memb[as.character(a$ID.x)]

  ID.x ID.y var.x var.y ID_group
1    1    2    55    86        1
2    2    4    82    24        1
3    3    5    32    68        1
4    1    3    94    63        1
5    6    7    55    77        2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am testing it now. What does igraph do under the hood to estimate it?

Comment: @GiulioCentorame exactly what youexpained in your code. thatsw why i used it

Comment: Thanks! But how is it that fast? Sorry for the naive question, but all the conditional statements solutions I can think of would require ages to be run

Comment: @GiulioCentorame haha. Once reading through your question, i realized you are dealing with components of a undirected graph, and just used the package. The codes are already written.

Comment: Thanks! So igraph estimates the components even though they are not connected with each other, right? Or components are independent element of a graph without edges connecting them?

Comment: @GiulioCentorame they are all connected. Note that it is a graph. There is no direct edge yet you can start from one vertex and make it to the other. Thats what a component is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242167/discussion-between-giulio-centorame-and-onyambu).